# How to stop Webpack wrapping my JS in an IIFE so I can call my functions in .cshtml views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webpack, .net-core

I've recently added WebPack 5 to my build process in my .NET Core MVC 7 application.

My goal is to be able to call my javascript functions from the javascript files WebPack generates inside my views.

I have a simple `Index.cshtml` file that includes a partial view and the **generated** javascript from webpack:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div>
    @await Html.PartialAsync("SettingsTab")
</div>
@section Scripts
{
    <script defer src="~/dist/settings.entry.js"></script>
}
```

The `SettingsTab` constains a button that is trying to trigger a method from the `settings.entry.js` file:

**SettingsTab.cshtml**

```
<div>
     <button type="button" onclick="saveProfileSettings()">Save Profile</button>
</div>
```

The `settings.js` file **before** webpack bundles it into the dist folder looks like this:

**settings.js**
import ('../css/settings.css')

function saveProfileSettings() {
// do stuff
}

When I wasn't using webpack I could directly call this function like I am trying to above.

However now when I reference the bundled js file it cannot call it.

Looking at the end of the `settings.entry.js` file it looks like webpack has bundled my code into an IIFE:

**End of settings.entry.js**

```
/************************************************************************/
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
// This entry need to be wrapped in an IIFE because it need to be in strict mode.
(() => {
"use strict";

// omitted contents of settings.js

})();

/******/ })()
;
```

I would like to instruct WebPack not to wrap my code like this so I can directly call the functions elsewhere.

Now I did find out that I can use `library` in my `webpack.config.js` like so:

```
output: {
    filename: "[name].entry.js",
    path: path.resolve('wwwroot', 'dist'),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    library: ['WebPack', '[name]']
},
```

With this I can successfully reference my functions using `WebPack.settings.saveProfileSettings()` but I do not want to do this. I want to be able to reference my functions directly as `saveProfileSettings()`.

How can I change how WebPack packs my code so I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the iife [setting](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputiife) to `false`:

```
output: {
    iife: false
},
```